# ngResource update method confusion

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I have looked at various tutorials and answers for various question regarding the usage of the update method, but so far non of that I have found actually works for me.

My service looks like this:

```
angular.module("testApp").service("PersonData", function($resource) {
    return $resource("api/persons/:id", {
        id: "@_id"
    }, {
        update: {
            method: "PUT"
        }
    });
});
```

I have tried various things in my controller such as:

```
PersonData.get({id:id})
    .$promise.then(function(result) {
      result.name = "new";
      result.$update();
    });
```

and

```
  var x = new PersonData({id: id});
          x.name = "new";

          x.update();
```

Each time I get an error which says `update is not a function`. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try the below sample code, but one obvious issue is that you need to Dependency Inject $resource as a parameter to your service ['$resource']

**try**:

```
 angular.module("testApp").service("PersonData", ['$resource', function($resource) {
     return $resource("api/persons/:id", {
         id: "@_id"
     }, {
         update: {
             url: 'url for update path', //an option
             method: "PUT",
             params: {
                 id: "@_id"
             }
         }
     });
 }]);
```

**then**: invoke the PersonData service in a controller:

```
var invoked = PersonData.update({
         id:: myID
     })
     .$promise.then(function(data) {
        // do something with a callback here if needed.
        // (Like an alert or another update, etc.) 
     });
```